# Form Speed Analyzer for Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to help a friend speed up a slow winforms app (Don't usually work with winforms allot).  I believe the majority of the issues are Database calls however there is quite a bit going on.  For WebDev there are a ton of great apps to analyze Page Load Event, Latency's, and Bottlenecks.  Is anyone familiar with and comparable tools for the winforms arena ?

Thanks All !

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 has good tools baked in.  Analyze menu.  Otherwise, check into ANTS.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I've played with the Built in Profiler, Is there a way to integrate it to monitor Database calls ?  Seems a little weak in that department (but then again I'm a little weak in the winforms department lol)

Comment: I use [Telerik's JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx). It works extremely well, especially for WinForms and ASP.NET applications. It integrates right into Visual Studio and it does both memory leak profiling and performance profiling.

Comment: That's where ANTS would do better.  But you have to buy it.  I've had it for a few years, and it's quite nice.  I use VS analyzers for on-the-spot info, and ANTS when I'm finalizing code to get deeper details.  And yes, it has network and database activity info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any .NET performance profiler will tell you where the time is spent - there is one in certain levels of VS, and several commercial ones (JetBrains, RedGate).

If it is in a database call, you'll be able to work out which one, and look at that.

One problem I've seen in naive WinForms apps can be a lot of stuff being called more than once, particularly when a form opens - it's easy to hook some kind of 'changed' event on a control, which then fires when you're filling in a form, which in turn triggers more changes and then more events.  Sometimes you've redrawn everything on the form two or three times before it all settles down.  An instrumenting profiler which can track function calls accurately will show you this going on.

Comment: And if it does turn out to be a slow SQL query, I suggest using SQL Profiler and SSMS's View Execution Plan feature to examine the queries.